# Looking for a getdate/dateadd statement to do 1 year and +/- 15 days

Tags: sql

-- This is my current code which will allow for me to see all our work orders that have been submitted within the past week, and lets me know if any of the same work orders have appear 6 months ago.

```
SELECT 
  A.tagnumber, 
  count(*) AS CountTotal
FROM 
  v_workorder A 
WHERE 
  --Date range Within Today and 6 months ago
  wo_requestDate BETWEEN DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE() 
  AND
    EXISTS 
    ( -- Date range Within Today and 7 days ago
      select 
        tagnumber 
      FROM 
        v_workorder 
      WHERE 
        wo_requestDate BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY,-7,GETDATE()) AND GETDATE() 
    ) 
  AND
  A.wc_description = 'Corrective'       
  AND           
  A.itemtype_name = 'Building'
GROUP BY A.tagnumber
ORDER BY CountTotal DESC
```

--However, Now I would like for my first variable of the getdate/adddate. To check back 1 year ago, +/- 15 days. So essentially 1 year and 15 days back instead of 6 months.

Comment: . . I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: Do you actually have a question?

Comment: yes lol. My question is how can I use a getdate statement to go back 1 year and 15 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For past 1 year +/- 15 Days**

```
SELECT A.tagnumber, count(*) AS CountTotal
 FROM v_workorder A 
 WHERE wo_requestDate BETWEEN DATEADD(day, -15, DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE())) AND DATEADD(day, 15, DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE()))
    AND
        EXISTS ( select tagnumber FROM v_workorder WHERE  wo_requestDate BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY,-7,GETDATE()) AND GETDATE() )
    AND
            A.wc_description = 'Corrective'     AND         A.itemtype_name = 'Building'
 GROUP BY A.tagnumber
 ORDER BY CountTotal DESC
```

**For 1 year**

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE wo_requestDate BETWEEN DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
AND...;
```

**For 15 Days**

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE wo_requestDate BETWEEN DATEADD(day, -15, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
AND...;
```

Other possible options of `DATEADD()`

```
year
quarter
month
dayofyear
day
week
weekday
hour
minute
second
millisecond
```

See more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_dateadd.asp).

.

Comment: Thank you, however, I would like to know if it is possible to go back 1 year and 15 days on one line. Instead of 2 separate statements.

Comment: Please see the updated answer. I am assuming you are looking for records lies between {-1year -15 Days} to {-1 year +15 days}.

Answer (score 0):

To eliminate issues with the time component of datetime:

`CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE`

Find the date from a year ago:

```
SELECT DATEADD(YEAR, -1, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE));
```

From there, subtract 15 days and add 15 days in your end points.

```
...
WHERE 
  wo_requestDate >= DATEADD(DAY, -15, DATEADD(YEAR, -1, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)))
  AND
  wo_requestDate < DATEADD(DAY, 15, DATEADD(YEAR, -1, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)))
```

I prefer `>=` and `<` to `BETWEEN`, especially with dates, just to avoid any ambiguity with the time component, so you may want to add 16 days to the last parameter if you want the range to include the 15th day out.

Comment: Thank you Eric, I will give this a try. It looks like itll work for me.